# Why is C# tightly coupled to .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, roslyn

In C++, Either C++ code can be compiled by a compiler or used in a C++ framework like Platinum. I mean, you have the choice to run C++ independently without frameworks. The same story goes for python and other languages. But come to C# world, I think (maybe I am wrong) you have no choice to run C# independetly by a compiler; it's coupled to dotNet framework or mono. Are there other languages that behave like C# and need its framework to run? Or only C# behave that way?

Comment: java (as well as clojure, kotlin, scala), erlang/elixir are similar  they run on their own runtimes.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-net-framework/

Comment: javascript can be run in browser, C# can be run on .net runtime, .net runtime can be run if there is respective C adapter for your system (mono, net framework, net core, etc).

Comment: you are wrong. you can use c# without the .net framework. there's just no point in it, because the framework is extremely powerful, and without it, you only have very basic features availabe.

Comment: Using .Net Core you can build a self-contained EXE  which doesn't require the framework installed in order to run.

Comment: What do you mean by python running independently?

Comment: @MatthewWatson But it has .net core SDKs with it inside the container. (I think so)

Comment: Do you really use C++ independently or do you rely upon the standard library?

Comment: @tymtam I mean, I have installed a python interpreter. I can run the code only with the installed interpreter without the need for a framework like Django, Flask, etc.

Comment: also: "why is this that way?" is a bad question for stackoverflow. too broad, opinion-based, and it'd be much better to ask the developers of c# about the "why".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In this context, I talk about framework and language. By independent, I mean it runs without a framework, not standard or other libraries.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks for the suggestion. I have removed that phrase. "Why is this that way?"

Comment: Well in that case, you can think of .NET as the "standard library" for C#, even though the ".NET _framework_" is a thing, it's just a name. It's not an "external library" in the sense that Django and Flask are external libraries.

Comment: The thing is this: .NET Framework (as well as .NET Core and Mono) aren't *just* frameworks, they're also runtimes. Think of installing the .NET Core runtime in the same manner as installing a Python interpreter, both are shipped with a set of standard classes and methods known as the standard library. There are then frameworks that built atop those Runtimes, like ASP.NET. Yes it's called .NET *Framework* but it's not really a framework

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I have no idea how I can do that. I can't run C# without .Net or mono. I have freshly installed windows. Let me know how I can run a simple hello world program.

Comment: @NaveedHematmal the first step would be to write your own implementation of `Console.WriteLine()` so you don't need the functionality that the framework provides. but the main question is: ***why*** do you not want to use the framework?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't hate frameworks. I want to know that if I can run C# without .Net. I want to separate the framework concept from the language.

Comment: "you have the choice to run C++ independently without frameworks" Well, generally C++ exes are linked to libraries which provide the implementation of things like `printf()`. C++ relies on a framework for IO.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah! I have got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two answers to this question.

## The framework

I think this is just a battle of words.

Python has an interpreter and comes with "batteries included" meaning a large standard library. That interpreter and libraries included by default is python's ***runtime environment***.

.NET is the ***runtime environment*** for C#. It for example includes the virtual machine required to run C# programs.

Please also remember that framework is just a term and it's used at many levels. For example, ASP.NET is also a framework but it's meaning is different to .NET Framework, it's a framework on another level.

### Mono is *not* .NET Framework

It is important to point out. mono is not .NET Framework and it's a real life proof that C# is **not** coupled to .NET Framework.

## Why C# not completely independent of .NET?

C# was created as part of and for .NET.

Comment: Thank you for the explanatory answer. You have said a framework on a different level. Can you explain that a little bit? And give an example.

Comment: ASP.NET is a set of tools (aka a framework) for building websites. It runs on .NET which is a framework for running applications. Someone can build a framework for building internet shops that runs on ASP.NET. 

Another example is Entity Framework on top of ADO.NET on top of .NET.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know that if I can run C# without .Net. I want to separate the framework concept from the language.

If you look into the C# spec, [ECMA 334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/), you'll see that it says:

> Although Microsoft’s implementation of C# relies on CLI for library and run-time support, other implementations of C# need not, provided they support an alternate way of getting at the minimum CLI features required by this C# standard (see Annex C).

CLI (Common Language Infrastructure) is based on a subset of the .NET Framework, as the standard says, so C#, the language, indeed does not rely on .NET. It only relies on the things listed in "Annex C", which you can see for yourself.

However, Microsoft's C# compiler, a specific implementation of the C# language *does* rely on .NET.

Also note that C# with only the things listed in Annex C is not going to be very powerful. I can't even find the `System.Console` class there. I wouldn't think that you will be able to write any practical program with only the things in Annex C, so at a practical level, yes C# does rely on .NET very much.

Comment: Thank you! one more question!
Can a language run without a standard library? Or is all the syntax of the language in the standard library. And can't do anything without including the standard library.

Comment: @NaveedHematmal In the context of this question, it doesn't make sense to say whether a _language_ runs or not. A "language" is really just a set of rules and the semantics associated with those rules, an ephemeral thing. The _runnable_ thing is some _implementation_ of the language. For example, you can write a program that takes in a string that is the source code, and outputs some data, **according to the rules and semantics of a language**. You can certainly write an implementation of C# that only has only those things in Annex C (closest you can get to "without a standard library")

Comment: Microsoft's implementation of C# _does depend on the .NET framework_, and Mono's implementation of C# also depends on the Mono framework. Also note that .NET framework, .NET Core, and Mono are all implementations of yet another ephemeral thing - the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Comment: @NaveedHematmal Wait I think I used "ephemeral" incorrectly here. I meant intangible.